# lost vs2010 pro disc can I convert trial for same effect?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I did a digital download of the iso for visual studio 2010 professional back a couple of years ago. When I got this iso I gave it to a coworker and asked for him to burn a few copies of the disc. I tried to use one of these discs the other day and they were not burned properly. I also lost the original iso from the download so I can't make another disc.

I found a trial version of visual studio 2010 professional which appears to be able to take a license key and convert for full usage according to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442061.aspx).

My question is if there is any difference in the build of the trial other than including some sort of lock out mechanism for when the trial days run out? Will I be missing menus like express version does? Will I be able to use power productivity tools and xceed datagrid, as well as other 3rd party add ins?

My only other vs2010 backup is a "web installer" which I do not want to archive going forward because at some future date that installer may not work.

My hopes are that someone can confirm for me that the trial with a legitimate license is pretty much the same build as my original pressed disc.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must edit the file setup.sdb from the Trial ISO and change the product key there. Now create a new ISO and install it.